# POSTGRESQL - Query does not return the data I need

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to do the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    companies
 WHERE
    companies.id IN (
    SELECT
        product_stocks.company_id
    FROM
        product_stocks
    WHERE 
        product_stocks.product_id = 1
    AND
        product_stocks.product_id = 9
  )
```

This query returns nothing. I would like this query to return only the companies if you have the 2 products (ids 1 and 9). And there are companies with these conditions in the database. I also tried with IN but it returns all companies that have id 1 or id 9 and that doesn't work. Does anyone know any way to make this query work?

Comment: I already read it here. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-logical.html. But I still found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking where rows EXIST "query to return only the companies if you have the 2 products (ids 1 and 9):

```
select *
  from companies c
 where exists (select null 
                 from product_stocks ps1 
                where c.company_id = ps1.company_id 
                  and ps1.product_id = 1
              )
   and exists (select null 
                 from product_stocks ps9 
                where c.company_id = ps9.company_id 
                  and ps9.product_id = 9
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'OR' clause rather than 'AND'.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    companies
 WHERE
    companies.id IN (
    SELECT
        product_stocks.company_id
    FROM
        product_stocks
    WHERE 
        product_stocks.product_id = 1
    OR
        product_stocks.product_id = 9
  )
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    companies
 WHERE
    companies.id IN (
    SELECT
        product_stocks.company_id
    FROM
        product_stocks
    WHERE 
        product_stocks.product_id IN (1,9)
  )
```

Comment: I already tried to use it that way. For me, it doesn't do. It returns all companies. I just want him to return ONLY if he has both IDs. With that, you have to use AND. I just don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns no records, simply because no record in product_stocks can have a product_id of 1 and 9 simultaneously. If you want to use a sub select to restrict the company IDs, then one way to do it is like this:

`SELECT * FROM companies
WHERE companies.id IN (
SELECT ps1.company_id 
FROM product_stocks ps1 
INNER JOIN product_stocks ps9 
ON ps1.company_id = ps9.company_id
WHERE ps1.product_id = 1 AND ps9.product_id = 9)`

By way of explanation, the inner (self) join in the sub select guarantees that only company IDs are returned which have both product_ids 1 and 9.